# How to hide Gtk Popup Window when user clickes outside the window

Tags: c, gtk

I have developed one popup window (Non decorated) using GTK+ and glade tool in C. 
It popup on its parent window when a button clicked. I want to destroy or hide this popup window when user clicks out side this window. User can click on parent window or any other window. 
I have tried to capture `GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE` event but I am not able to capture this event. Is there any way to achieve this? How do I know that click is on other window then pop up window? How is it clear that pop up window has lost it's focus? 
So that I can hide it. 
The relevant code is as follow:

```
/*
 * Compile me with:

 gcc -o popup popup.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0)
*/

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_popup_clicked (GtkButton*, GtkWidget*);
static gboolean on_popup_window_event(GtkWidget*, GdkEventExpose*);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *button, *vbox;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Parent window");
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 300, 300);
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Pop Up");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked",G_CALLBACK (on_popup_clicked),(gpointer) window);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 3);
    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX (vbox), button, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}

void on_popup_clicked (GtkButton* button, GtkWidget* pWindow)
{
    GtkWidget *popup_window;
    popup_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), "Pop Up window");
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (popup_window), 10);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (popup_window, 150, 150);
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW (popup_window),GTK_WINDOW (pWindow));
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "event",
                        G_CALLBACK (on_popup_window_event),NULL);

    GdkColor color;
    gdk_color_parse("#3b3131", &color);
    gtk_widget_modify_bg(GTK_WIDGET(popup_window), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);


    gtk_widget_show_all (popup_window);
}

gboolean on_popup_window_event(GtkWidget *popup_window, GdkEventExpose *event)
{
    if(event->type == GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE)
        gtk_widget_hide (popup_window);

    return FALSE;
}
```

Here I am not able to hide this pop up window when user clicks on parent window or on other window. How can I do this?

I have to stick with Gtk+2.14 version.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. This appears to be a (better presented) repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740947/problem-with-gtk-popup-window-focus-change-event-handling

Comment: I will take care of this in future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changes:

- switch from `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` to `GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL`, counter-intuitive, but I could not figure out how to get a popup to accept focus.
- add `gtk_window` hints to prevent popup from showing in taskbar and pager
- intentionally set the focus on the popup window
- set the `GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK` on the `GDK_WINDOW` with `gtk_widget_set_events` (required for the next step)
- connect to the `focus-out-event` of the popup window
- change the signal handler to handle a different signal

I would also suggest reading the GTK+ source to see how it handles popup windows for tooltips and menus when they are shown... but those are usually destroyed based on the mouse moving out of range, not the popup losing focus, per se.

```
#include 

static void on_popup_clicked (GtkButton*, GtkWidget*);
gboolean on_popup_focus_out (GtkWidget*, GdkEventFocus*, gpointer);

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window, *button, *vbox;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Parent window");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 300, 300);
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Pop Up");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button),
                    "clicked",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_popup_clicked),
                    (gpointer) window);

  vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 3);
  gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}

void
on_popup_clicked (GtkButton* button, GtkWidget* pWindow)
{
  GtkWidget *popup_window;

  popup_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), "Pop Up window");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (popup_window), 10);
  gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), FALSE);
  gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), FALSE);
  gtk_window_set_skip_taskbar_hint (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), TRUE);
  gtk_window_set_skip_pager_hint (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), TRUE);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (popup_window, 150, 150);
  gtk_window_set_transient_for (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), GTK_WINDOW (pWindow));
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  gtk_widget_set_events (popup_window, GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (popup_window),
                    "focus-out-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_popup_focus_out),
                    NULL);

  GdkColor color;
  gdk_color_parse ("#3b3131", &color);
  gtk_widget_modify_bg (GTK_WIDGET (popup_window), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);

  gtk_widget_show_all (popup_window);
  gtk_widget_grab_focus (popup_window);
}

gboolean
on_popup_focus_out (GtkWidget *widget,
                    GdkEventFocus *event,
                    gpointer data)
{
  gtk_widget_destroy (widget);
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Good deal. If this answer works for you, feel free to click the big check mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: Great solution, but there is one problem: The main window is visually registering the focus changes by coloring the border differently (Windows 7). This should not happen for a (fake) popup window. Any idea to prevent this?

Comment: To make it clear, here are some screenshots: http://imageshack.us/g/211/beforegp.png/ (have a look at the icons for example)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set keyboard focus to your popup window.

You just need to capture mouse to your `popup_window->window` using `gdk_pointer_grab(...)` with True `owner_events` and GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK `GdkEventMask` arguments.

Then connect your popup_window to `"button-press-event"`. Inside it's handler hide/destroy your popup_window and release capture using `gdk_pointer_ungrab(...)` if *event coordinates are negative or higher than your popup_window size.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to simply add a button press listener to the parent window. This has the advantage that the popup window still looks like a popup (both the parent and itself can be active at once)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_popup_clicked (GtkButton*, GtkWidget*);

gulong handler_id;

gboolean
on_click (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
{
  g_signal_handler_disconnect (widget, handler_id);
  gtk_widget_destroy (user_data);
  return TRUE;
}


gboolean
on_popup_focus_out (GtkWidget *widget,
                    GdkEventFocus *event,
                    gpointer data)
{
  gtk_widget_destroy (widget);
  return TRUE;
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window, *button, *vbox;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Parent window");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 300, 300);
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Pop Up");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button),
                    "clicked",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_popup_clicked),
                    (gpointer) window);

  vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 3);
  gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}

void
on_popup_clicked (GtkButton* button, GtkWidget* pWindow)
{
  GtkWidget *popup_window;

  popup_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), "Pop Up window");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (popup_window), 10);
  gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), FALSE);
  gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), FALSE);
  gtk_window_set_skip_taskbar_hint (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), TRUE);
  gtk_window_set_skip_pager_hint (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), TRUE);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (popup_window, 150, 150);
  gtk_window_set_transient_for (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), GTK_WINDOW (pWindow));
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (popup_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  gtk_widget_add_events (popup_window, GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK);
  gtk_widget_add_events (pWindow, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (popup_window),
                    "focus-out-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_popup_focus_out),
                    NULL);

  handler_id = g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (pWindow),
                    "button-press-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_click),
                    popup_window);

  GdkColor color;
  gdk_color_parse ("#3b3131", &color);
  gtk_widget_modify_bg (GTK_WIDGET (popup_window), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);

  gtk_widget_show_all (popup_window);
  gtk_widget_grab_focus (popup_window);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is actually pointed to by @Brylev Daniel.

The following should provide a proof of concept:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void destroy_window(GtkWidget *window, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data) {
  gdouble x = event->button.x;
  gdouble y = event->button.y;
  gint w, h;
  gtk_window_get_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), &w, &h);
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > w || y > h) {
    gdk_pointer_ungrab(event->button.time);
    gtk_widget_destroy(window);
  }
}

void make_window(){
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gdk_pointer_grab(gtk_widget_get_window(window), TRUE, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK, NULL, NULL, GDK_CURRENT_TIME);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(destroy_window), NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  make_window();
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```